# Javascript my function parameter is undefined when console.logging

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters, console.log

I'm creating a function that searches for the current part of the array that you are at. I've already created something like this before, but somehow it says that my param is undefined when i try to console.log it. I've already searched multiple simulair questions, but I couldn't find a right answer for me.

```
        /**
         * @param {int} DesIndex
         * @param {int} question
         * @returns {QuizPart}
         */
        openModal(question, DesIndex) {
            let questionIndex = this.quiz[DesIndex]
            console.log(DesIndex)
            console.log(questionIndex)
```

Now this.quiz is the array that I'm in (It's multidimentional). This already worked in other code that looked exactly the same, but not in here. In the other code, when I console log the parameter it would say the number of the part of the array where I'm at, but here it's undefined.

logged function

```
infoModal {quiz: Array(3), questionsArray: Array(0), modal: div#myModal.modal, questionNumber: 0, div: div#modal-content.modal-content, …}
body: div#containerID.container
div: div#modal-content.modal-content
modal: div#myModal.modal
nextbtn: button#nextbtn.nextbtn
prevbtn: button#prevbtn.prevbtn
questionNumber: 0
questionsArray: []
quiz: (3) [QuizPart, QuizPart, QuizPart]
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

function itself

```
openModal: openModal(question, DesIndex) { //displays the modal if button is clicked // this.nextbtn.onclick = () => {…}
length: 2
name: "openModal"
arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.s (<anonymous>:1:83)]
caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.s (<anonymous>:1:83)]
[[FunctionLocation]]: index.html?_ijt=3msd…=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:258
```

When i console log te int itself it shows in the browser as a pointerEvent

Call function:

```
document.getElementById('openModal').addEventListener("click", InMod.openModal.bind(InMod));
```

Comment: This looks like you are passing an undefined value as the second argument to `openModal` at the time you call it.  Can you show the code where you call `openModal`?  e.g.: if you have `openModal(first, second)` I'd like to see that code.  Also, please take a moment to insert a `console.log(second)` *before* you call the function to confirm you aren't just passing it an undefined value.

Comment: @Wyck I'll add that part of the code, but I already deleted the other parameter and now it sees DesIndex as a pointerEvent instead of an integer

Comment: The first argument passed to an event listener callback is the event (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback)).  So the typically an onClick handler looks like `onClick(e)`.  the `e` is getting passed in as the `question` argument of your `openModal` function.  you need a click handler, you can't just substitute your openModal function as an event listener unless it _works_ like an event listener (takes the same args).

Comment: alright then I'lll try using an onclick function.

Comment: usually will look something like `.addEventListener("click", (e) => { InMod.openModal(someQuestion, someDesIndex); });` Where `e` is the event argument.  But be careful about creating closures like this and make sure everything in scope is valid at the time of the call.